# LocalDateTime stops working when adding "is null" condition

Tags: java, spring, rest, h2, jpql

I'm having the following issue:

I have a REST endpoint, with a controller and a repository. I'm trying to run a GET method. The following code works well:

Here's the Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/search/findmycalendar")
public ResponseEntity<Page<CalendarView>> getCalendar(
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "period")
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate period,
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "cutoff")
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime cutoff,
        @RequestParam("code") String code, Pageable pageable) {
    Page<CalendarView> cv2 =
            calendarR.getCalendarByCalendarPeriodCutoffDate(period, cutoff, code, pageable);
    if (cv2.getTotalElements() == 0) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(cv2);
    }

}
```

Here's the repository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT new CalendarView("
        + "calendar.id, "
        + "calendar.Rid, "
        + "calendar.code, "
        + "calendar.version ) "
        + "FROM ScaCalendar calendar "
        + " WHERE (calendar.calendarPeriod >= :calendarPeriod)  "
        + " AND (calendar.cutOffDateTime >= :cutoffDateTime)  "
        + " AND calendar.tenantCode = :tenantCode ")
Page<CalendarView> getCalendarByCalendarPeriodCutoffDate(
        @Param("calendarPeriod") LocalDate calendarPeriod,
        @Param("cutoffDateTime") LocalDateTime cutoffDateTime,
        @Param("tenantCode") String tenantCode,
        Pageable pageable);
```

This works PERFECTLY fine. However, when I add the "is null" condition to :cutoffDateTime parameter, shown below, it stops working:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT new CalendarView("
        + "calendar.id, "
        + "calendar.Rid, "
        + "calendar.code, "
        + "calendar.calendarPeriod, "
        + "calendar.cutOffDateTime, "
        + "calendar.version ) "
        + "FROM ScaCalendar calendar "
        + " WHERE (calendar.calendarPeriod >= :calendarPeriod)  "
        + " AND (calendar.cutOffDateTime >= :cutoffDateTime or :cutoffDateTime is null)  "
        + " AND calendar.tenantCode = :tenantCode ")
Page<CalendarView> getCalendarByCalendarPeriodCutoffDate(
        @Param("calendarPeriod") LocalDate calendarPeriod,
        @Param("cutoffDateTime") LocalDateTime cutoffDateTime,
        @Param("tenantCode") String tenantCode,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Here's the definition for CalendarView:

```
public class CalendarView {
private Long id;
private long Rid;
private String code;
private LocalDate calendarPeriod;
private LocalDateTime cutOffDateTime;
private long version;
```

}

Here's the error I get:
When I leave the cutoffDateTime parameter as null in my URL, it works perfectly fine and the is null condition is fulfilled. But when I give it a LocalDateTime Value (cutoffDateTime=2018-01-01T23:44:05.012Z) I get the following error:

"timestamp": 1533949418556,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException"...
Query here-----
\"; expected \"[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )\";

This only happens when adding the is null condition. If I remove the condition, and use the exact same URL with the exact same LocalDateTime Value for cutoffDateTime mentioned above, this works just fine. Is this a common issue?

Thank you so, so much for your time!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that when adding the "is null" condition to calendarPeriod, which is a LocalDate, I don't have any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not support LocalDate / LocalDateTime yet.

You should provide an `AttributeConverter`:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDate) {

    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {

    }
}
```